# Magento 2 Currency Switch Dropdown - Remove currency name

Tags: magento2, currency

In Magento 2 (Luma child theme) when enabling multiple currencies you get a currency switcher dropdown in the frontend's header.
By default, it shows the **currency code followed by the full name,**

> e.g. GBP - British Pound Sterling.

**I want to keep GBP, USD etc.**
But remove the rest as I think it's unnecessary, customers can tell the currency from the code.
I am new to Magento 2 and can't find where in the template or layout files this can be changed.

Any idea?

Comment: Hello @webrightnow, Have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 2):

copy file:

> mage2Root/vendor/magento/module-directory/view/frontend/templates/currency.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Directory/templates/currency.phtml

After that you need to remove `Currency code`.

Code responsible for showing currency code is:

```
- <?= @$block->escapeHtml($currencies[$currentCurrencyCode]) ?>
```

Above code will remove active currency code.
For other currency code you need to remove:

```
- <?= $block->escapeHtml($_name) ?>
```

from `li`

Before edit:

[image]

After Edit:

[image]

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 2):

Original FIle path

```
vendor\magento\module-directory\view\frontend\templates\currency.phtml
```

Override file in your child theme and past below code

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Directory\templates\currency.phtml

<?php if ($block->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<?php $currencies = $block->getCurrencies(); ?>
<?php $currentCurrencyCode = $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
<div class="switcher currency switcher-currency" id="switcher-currency<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Currency')) ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
             id="switcher-currency-trigger<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             data-trigger-keypress-button="true">
            <strong class="language-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentCurrencyCode()) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($currentCurrencyCode) ?></span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php foreach ($currencies as $_code => $_name): ?>
                <?php if ($_code != $currentCurrencyCode): ?>
                    <li class="currency-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?> switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSwitchCurrencyPostData($_code) ?>'><?= $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Trust Magento to hide templates in directories where no newbie developer will ever think to look. "Module-directory"? How does that name in ANY way relate to currency? Why not "Module-currency"? Go figure...